# How is this (xy)' + (yz) simplified into this (x’+y’)+z in boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, simplify

I not understand how the first Boolean expression on the question can be simplified into the last. Please help me.

**My attempt:**

**1.** **(xy)' + (yz)**

**2.** **(x' + y') + (yz)** `# Using de Morgan's law`.

**3.** **x' + (y' + yz)** `# First Distribution axiom`.

**4.** **x' + (y' + y) * (y'z) `# Rewriting`**

**5.** **x' + 1 * (y'z) `# Law of Inverse.`**

**6.** **x' + y' + z `# 2nd Identitiy axiom.`**

But the final answer is supposed to be `(x’+y’)+z` !

I am using the following book:

```
Discrete Mathematics for Computing / Edition 3
by Peter Grossman
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with your notation.  Are we to understand that `'` signifies negation ("not"), `+` signifies disjunction ("or") and `*` or direct juxtaposition signifies conjunction ("and")?

Comment: The **asterisk (*)** means **AND**.

Comment: Are you familiar with the expression "you can't get there from here"?

Comment: @JohnBollinger ?

Comment: I'm saying that the expression applies to your efforts.  In response to seeing you adding steps to the attempt presented in this question, I am repeating what I already said in my answer: you cannot get "there" -- to the formula `x * y` that you are trying to reach -- from "here", the starting formula `(xy)' + (yz)`, by any valid sequence of boolean algebra steps.  The desired conclusion does not follow from the premise.  Continuing your efforts will only tire and frustrate you.

Comment: If you want to ask a different question then ask it *as* a different question.  Do not edit your question into a wholly different one, particularly after you already have answers.  I have rolled back the edit that did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(xy)’+yz

(x’ +y’)+yz (2nd de Morgan's axiom)

x’ + (y’ +yz) (1st Association axiom)

x’+ (y’+y)(y’+z) (1st Distribution axiom)

x’ + 1(y’+z) (1st Inverse axiom)

x’+ (y’+z) (1st Identity axiom)

(x’+y’)+z (1st Association axiom)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is unfamiliar to me, but I'm reading the first formula as:

```
(not ( x and y )) or ( y and z )
```

and the second as:

```
x and y
```

That seems consistent with your application of de Morgan's.

In that case, observe that when `y` is false, the first formula evaluates to true and the second evaluates to false, regardless of the values of `x` and `z`.  **Thus, the first formula does not imply the second. The simplification you are looking for cannot (validly) be performed**.

Comment: Hi John, this is an expression `(xy)' + xy` and when simplified using the proper Boolean Laws (https://byjus.com/maths/boolean-algebra-laws/), results in `x * y` according to the last pages of my book that contains the final answer, but not the full steps to derive that answer.

Comment: @AlixBlaine, I know the laws of Boolean algebra well, thank you.  I'm telling you that the premise of your question is mistaken.  Possibly there is an error in one of the two formulae you presented, but as given in the question, the first cannot be simplified to the second.  This answer *proves* that by showing that there are (many) cases where the first evaluates to true but the second to false.

Comment: Furthermore, if `x = true` and `y = true` first formula evaluates to `z`.